# AWS Cloudformation template for a codepipeline with jenkins build stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I need to write a CFT for pipeline with Jenkins integration for build/test. I found this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html) to setup `ActionTypeId` for the jenkins stage. But this doc does not specify how to set the `server url` of the **jenkins server**. And also it is not clear to me where to give the **Jenkins Provider name**. Is it in the `ActionTypeId` or in `configuration` properties?

I could not find any example for this use case in the internet as well.

Please provide a proper example for setup Jenkins Action Provider for AWS Codepipeline using AWS Cloudformation template.

Following is a section from the sample cft I wrote from what I learnt from above doc.

```
"stages": [
    {
        "name": "Jenkins",
        "actions": [
            ...
            {
                "name": "Jenkins Build",
                "actionTypeId": {
                    "category": "Build",
                    "owner": "Custom",
                    "provider": "Jenkins",
                    "version": "1"
                },
                "runOrder": 2,
                "configuration": {
                    ???
                },
                ...
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Please narrow the focus to some specific problem. As it stands now, your post essentially is "please write my CF template for me".  
No.

Comment: @lexicore My specific problem is stated as "But this doc does not specify how to set the server url of the jenkins server. And also it is not clear to me where to give the Jenkins Provider name. Is it in the ActionTypeId or in configuration properties?"

Comment: I asked for te sample since I could not find a sample for this use case, anywhere in the internet. And it would be good to have it somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of information which was missing for me was that I need to create a [Custom Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-create-custom-action.html) to use Jenkins as the Action provider for my codepipeline.

First I added the custom action as below:

```
JenkinsCustomActionType: 
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::CustomActionType
    Properties: 
        Category: Build 
        Provider: !Ref JenkinsProviderName
        Version: 1
        ConfigurationProperties: 
            - 
                Description: "The name of the build project must be provided when this action is added to the pipeline." 
                Key: true 
                Name: ProjectName 
                Queryable: false
                Required: true 
                Secret: false 
                Type: String 
        InputArtifactDetails: 
            MaximumCount: 5
            MinimumCount: 0 
        OutputArtifactDetails: 
            MaximumCount: 5
            MinimumCount: 0 
        Settings: 
            EntityUrlTemplate: !Join ['', [!Ref JenkinsServerURL, "/job/{Config:ProjectName}/"]]
            ExecutionUrlTemplate: !Join ['', [!Ref JenkinsServerURL, "/job/{Config:ProjectName}/{ExternalExecutionId}/"]]
        Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: custom-jenkins-action-type
```

> The jenkins server URL is given in the `settings` for Custom Action
>   and the Jenkins provider name is given for `Provider`. Which were the
>   issues I had initially.

Then configure the pipeline stage as following:

```
DevPipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    DependsOn: JenkinsCustomActionType
    Properties:
        Name: Dev-CodePipeline
        RoleArn:
            Fn::GetAtt: [ CodePipelineRole, Arn ]
        Stages:
            ...
            - Name: DevBuildVerificationTest
              Actions:
                  - Name: JenkinsDevBVT
                    ActionTypeId:
                        Category: Build
                        Owner: Custom
                        Version: 1
                        Provider: !Ref JenkinsProviderName
                    Configuration:
                        # JenkinsDevBVTProjectName - Jenkins Job name defined as a parameter in the CFT
                        ProjectName: !Ref JenkinsDevBVTProjectName
                    RunOrder: 4
```

The Custom Action has to be created before the Pipeline. Hence `DependsOn: JenkinsCustomActionType`